# Show that the spherical tensor (1)_ij is the Kronecker's delta?

Tags: tensor-products, tensors

I am thinking the problem that show that

\begin{equation}
(\textbf{1})_{ij} = \delta_{ij}
\end{equation}

**My attempt**

The unit tensor is a spherical tensor

\begin{equation}
\textbf{1} = \textbf{e}_{i} \otimes \textbf{e}_{i}
\end{equation}

Then we get probably the following.
I am not sure which subscript I should use in (2).

\begin{equation}
(\textbf{e}_{i} \otimes \textbf{e}_{i})_{ij} 
= \textbf{e}_{i} \cdot 
(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}_{j}
\end{equation}

and then we want to give input $e_{i}$ to this such that it gives out the scalar 1.

So probably

\begin{equation}
\Bigl( 
\textbf{e}_{i} \cdot 
(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}_{j}
\Bigr)
\textbf{e}_{i} 
=
\textbf{e}_{i} \cdot
\Bigl( 
(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}_{j}
\Bigr)
\textbf{e}_{i} 
\end{equation}

Then we have consider what it means to give as an input to the this tensor something.

So I am stucked here

\begin{equation}
\Bigl( 
(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}_{j}
\Bigr)
\textbf{e}_{i} 
\end{equation}

### Case $i = j$

So if i = j, then $e_{i} = e$ and $e_{j} = e$ and
\begin{equation}
\Bigl( 
(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}
\Bigr)
\textbf{e},
\end{equation}
where $(\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e})\textbf{e} = (\textbf{e} \cdot \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}$. 
The tensor $\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e}$ maps each vector $\textbf{e}$ to the projection $(\textbf{e} \cdot \textbf{e}) \textbf{e}$ of $\textbf{e}$ onto the vector $\textbf{e}$, where $\textbf{e} \cdot \textbf{e} = 1, $ scalar. So the result

\begin{equation}
\textbf{e} \otimes \textbf{e} = 1 \textbf{e} = \textbf{e}.
\end{equation}

### Case $i \not= j$

Problem here how to start.

**How can you show that the following?**

\begin{equation}
(\textbf{1})_{ij} = \delta_{ij}
\end{equation}

The exercise is from Gurtin's book of *The Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Continua* 2010, Exercise 2 where above some definitions that may be useful to show by basevectors:

[image]

Comment: The exercise is from the book of Gurtin, The Mechanics and Thermodynamics of Continua, 2010, after some definitions of tensors.

Comment: I was given a hint that this follows from the equation (2.9): $S_{ij} = (\bar{S})_{ij} = \bar{e}_{i} \cdot \bar{S} \bar{e}_{j}.$

Comment: How can you see the proof from this? I know that $\bar{S} = \alpha \bar{1}$, with $\alpha$ is a scalar, is called a spherical tensor. So we know that $\bar{S} = \alpha (e_{i} \bigotimes e_{i})$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the definition of the spherical tensor $\mathbf 1$:

$$
\mathbf 1 = \mathbf e_i \otimes \mathbf e_i
$$

Therefore, for any vector $\mathbf v$:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathbf{1v}&=(\mathbf e_i \otimes \mathbf e_i)(v_k \mathbf e_k) \\
&= v_k (\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_k)\mathbf e_i \\
&=v_k\delta_{ik}\mathbf e_i \\
&= v_i \mathbf e_i \\
&= \mathbf v
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, we can find the components of $\mathbf 1$ by using relation 2.9 in the book:

$$
\begin{aligned}
S_{ij} &= \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf{Se}_j \\
(\mathbf 1)_{ij} &= \mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf{1e}_j \quad \leftarrow \text{use the relation we showed above} \\
&=\mathbf e_i \cdot \mathbf e_j \\
&= \delta_{ij}
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: You have now in the second sentence $\mathbf e_{i} \otimes \mathbf e_{i}$. Should this be $\mathbf e_{i} \otimes \mathbf e_{j}$, like in definition?

Comment: If you have it, then you get $\delta_{jk} \mathbf e_{i}$. Can we change index $j$ now to $i$? Is it allowed and why?

Comment: Sorry, typo in definition. Edited now...

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I now understand what you meant.